# Arx Fatalis/Arx Liberatis Sequence Breaking?

Tags: arx-fatalis

Forgive the slew of colloquialisms and non-specific descriptors that will plague the discussion to follow.

First off, I am not

1. Very familiar with Arx Fatalis and how it works (and the updated for Windows-8 Arx Libertatis freeware)
2. Big on power/metagaming
3. Looking to break the game/deal with issues that come with it.

Now, Arx Fatalis is a game I just bought on Steam a couple days ago. It ran really weird, so I found the sort of unoffical patch for newer computers "Arx Libertatis" so that it would run smoothly. Basically, I am level four, haven't really taken the time to truly specialize in any fields, and am doing what I assume is the main quest. (I am investigating that guy who was murdered by cultists, the little girl was kidnapped and sacrificed because I failed to save her, etc.)

In that particular area, I came across a purple force field, which I assume Dispel Field will get rid of, I haven't actually tested it yet, but I was working on it. At that point, I noticed that there was an opportunity for platforming around the area, which I assumed may lead to some hidden goodies.

Here is the problem:

It lead me into a secret backdoor area into that weird pyramid thing full of snake people that said I wasn't ready to enter yet. I got in, opened the door (I was apparently in some form of treasure room that triggers hostility), died, tried again, THIS TIME WITH AN INVISIBILITY POTION. With that, I got into some form of throne room without being attacked, and spoke to a  red snake lady. Now my character is talking about a weapon called Zohark and killing this Akbaa fella and all this other crazy stuff I'm pretty sure I shouldn't know about yet.

So... does this break the game? I was under the impression that the game was very non-linear. I don't know what I'm supposed to do since the girl I was supposed to save and the demon and the cultists are dead. I found what I assume is another sequence break with some giant black beast that is unfightable, and very difficult to outrun, at which point I totally ditched the area because it scared me shitless.

I don't want to cause awkward holes in the games plot and skip/have to re-do anything or anything crazy. I mean, I already totally emptied that little treasure area. I'm just curious why they'd make the area so easily accessible if it skips an unknown portion of the plotline. I didn't 'metagame' or break anything, I just leaped up a clearly intentional alternate pathway, and through a clearly intentional hole in the pyramid thingy's side. Heck, there were even traps and baddies along the pathway. Is this just poor game design? I love the game so far.

I'm probably going to reload to before I talked to the snake lady. I'm just curious how people new to the game should go about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have broken the game and should probably reload.

The backdoor has some other uses, but early on in the game all you're really meant to do with it, if anything, is sneak in, loot the storage room it leads to, and leave. If you actually enter the complex proper that way all the snakepeople will turn hostile and things will go very badly for you -- that's probably not a fight you can win that early in the game, at least not legitimately.

However, there are some ways to break that scripting, all of them involving the invisibility potion, which prevents them from going hostile and lets you trigger conversations that aren't meant to happen until *much* later in the game.

There are other sequence breaks possible, but this is probably the easiest one to trigger by accident.

[Doug the Eagle's Anti-Walkthrough for Arx Fatalis](http://it-he.org/arx.htm) mentions this sequence break, among others (under section 21, *Sisters of Mercy*) -- but it's full of spoilers, so you should probably wait until you've finished the game normally before reading it.